# How to safety pass login and password form Angular to Spring Boot?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have designed an API which is JWT secured. I followed this:

[image]

However, credentials are passed explicitly to the backend. So anyone can view the login and password of the user.
So how to pass the login and password to from frontend the backend (for JWT generation) so that it is safe?
I am looking for best practices.

Comment: What do you mean with  “anyone can view the login and password of the user”? How? This is what https was invented for right?

Comment: Ok, so I understand that if I have https, I don't have to worry about anything anymore and this solution is enough?

Comment: Good enough for banks?

Comment: for books shop for example

Comment: Yes, HTTPS is all you need.  You can rest assured that this will protect your data, that is until quantum computers are readily available and your keys are easily compromised.  Optimistically, that's probably still many years down the road.

Comment: Thank you @lane.maxwell :) 
What if I don't have https? Can I somehow secure it on http?

Comment: If you cannot use HTTPS, encrypt the credentials before sending them.  Assuming asymmetric encryption, you'll need to share the public key with the service so it can correctly decrypt the payload.  Your software will be way easier to support; however, if you just front the service with TLS.

Comment: ok, its clear now, thank you for your help @lane.maxwell :)

Comment: How did you implement the logic of JWT. I have looked at various documentations but they are all deprecated. - @user3794273